# UML diagram feedback

Tags: design-patterns

I am currently learning design patterns and I have decided to develop a chess game.

**Factory Method Integration**: Factory is responsible for creating instances of the IGame interface based on user input. I plan to implement concrete game classes for chess and shogi, each adhering to the IGame interface and providing game-specific functionalities.
**Strategy Pattern Integration:** Strategy interfaces (IMovementStrategy, IGameRules, IAI) to encapsulate different aspects of the game's behavior. I want to implement concrete strategy classes for movement validation, game rules, and AI behavior, ensuring adherence to the respective interfaces. Integrate strategies into the game logic, allowing dynamic selection based on runtime conditions.
**State Pattern Integration:** I plan to design concrete state classes (PlayingState, CheckState, GameOverState) to manage the game's state transitions and behavior.

However I am not sure... if it isn't little bit too complicated[image]? I do want to learn and try but I don't want to kill the project by it. So to sum up, I would love to get some feedback on this.